# Rails tests reliant on time, issues using Timecop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, rspec

I have a model which deletes all records that have not been updated for more than two days. I am using an AR callback to trigger the relevant methods.

```
  CHECK_INTERVAL = 1.days
  RECORDS_GREATER_THAN = 2.days

  before_create :clear_old_records
  scope :unused_shopping_baskets, -> { where("updated_at < ? AND workflow_state=?", Time.zone.now - RECORDS_GREATER_THAN, 'basket') }

  def clear_old_records
    if ShoppingBasket.time_to_check?
      records = ShoppingBasket.unused_shopping_baskets
      if records
        records.destroy_all
      end
    end
  end

  def self.time_to_check?
    basket=self.first
    basket.present? ? basket.created_at<(Time.now-CHECK_INTERVAL) : true
  end
```

I have played around with this in the rails console, so I am quite confident it works. However I want to be able to say for certain by using tests, but dealing with time can be a headache, which is why I thought to use Timecop.

```
  let(:shopping_basket_1){FactoryGirl.create :shopping_basket}
        describe "deleting old baskets" do
    before do 
      shopping_basket_1
    end

    context "day one" do 

      it "records still exist" do 
        expect(ShoppingBasket.all.count).to eq 1
      end

      it "is time to check" do 
        expect(ShoppingBasket.time_to_check?).to be_falsey
      end
    end


    context "1 day in the future" do 
      before do 
        Timecop.travel(Time.zone.now + 24.hours) 
      end 

      it "is time to check" do 
        expect(ShoppingBasket.time_to_check?).to be_truthy
      end

      it "records still exist" do 
        expect(ShoppingBasket.all.count).to eq 1
      end

    end

    context "2 days in the future" do 
      before do 
        Timecop.travel(Time.zone.now + 48.hours)
      end 

      it "scope includes shopping_basket_1" do 
        expect(ShoppingBasket.unused_shopping_baskets).to include shopping_basket_1

      end

      it "is time to check" do 
        expect(ShoppingBasket.time_to_check?).to be_truthy
      end

      it "shopping_basket_1 no longer exist" do 
        expect(ShoppingBasket.all.count).to eq 0
      end
    end
  end
```

The last context however, fails. There is still 1 item in the DB. Also, when I inspect the scope on the last context, it shows up empty, when I expect it to include shopping_basket_1

```
  1) ShoppingBasket deleting old baskets 2 days in the future scope includes shopping_basket_1
     Failure/Error: expect(ShoppingBasket.unused_shopping_baskets).to include shopping_basket_1
       expected #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> to include #<ShoppingBasket id: 3614, created_at: "2014-11-08 14:06:17", updated_at: "2014-11-08 14:06:17", simple_contact_with_address_id: 3502, sagepay_security_key: nil, workflow_state: "basket", frozen_value: nil>
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -[#<ShoppingBasket id: 3614, created_at: "2014-11-08 14:06:17", updated_at: "2014-11-08 14:06:17", simple_contact_with_address_id: 3502, sagepay_security_key: nil, workflow_state: "basket", frozen_value: nil>]
       +[] 

  2) ShoppingBasket deleting old baskets 2 days in the future shopping_basket_1 no longer exist
     Failure/Error: expect(ShoppingBasket.all.count).to eq 0

       expected: 0
            got: 1

       (compared using ==)
```

examples are generated via factory girl

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :shopping_basket do
    simple_contact_with_address
    workflow_state "basket"
  end
end
```

What am I missing here? Is it my test or my code, or both?!

Thanks,

Comment: Please post the definition of `shopping_basket_1`, given that it is the examples therein that are failing. If those aren't the expectations that are failing, then your posted test doesn't match your results.

Comment: should your scope say updated_at <= ? (or conversely, should you be adding 48 hours and 1 second)  ?

Comment: Your error messages imply the existence of examples "includes shopping_basket_1" and "shopping_basket_1 no longer exist", but those examples don't exist in your post.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin apologies, I've been tinkering away. please see now

Comment: You're still not showing `deleting old baskets 2 days in the future scope includes shopping_basket_1`